# create color scale between two colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors

```
let colors = ["#5D2EE8", "#2F9EEE", "#2FC8EE", "#2DD91A", "#CBF22C",
              "#F2CE2C", "#F06E1D", "#E61717", "#3C2EA8", "#7A2EA1"];
let colorRange = d3.scale.quantile()
                   .domain([0, 31])
                   .range(colors);
```

I want to replace this implementation with the creation of a color palette of x colors between two colors ? 
For example I want to map my set of 90 numbers between 0 and 31 to 9 colors between yellow and red. Is this possible ?
I'm using v3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a sequential scale with a custom interpolator, or a threshold scale with a custom array of colors.

However, since you want to conveniently use any two colors as the start and end colors, I reckon that the easiest solution is using **two scales**.

The first one maps all the numbers from `0` to `31` to 9 values only:

```
var scale = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .range(d3.range(9))
    .domain([0, 31]);
```

Then, another scale maps those 9 values to 9 colors between any two given colors. In your case, `"yellow"` and `"red"`:

```
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range(["yellow", "red"])
    .domain([0, 9]);
```

I'm using v4 here, you can just change them to `d3.scale.quantize()` and `d3.scale.linear()`.

Here is a demo (also using v4), I'm creating 150 divs, each one representing a number between `0` and `31`. The output has only 9 colors:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .range(d3.range(9))
  .domain([0, 31]);
var colorScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range(["yellow", "red"])
  .domain([0, 9]);
var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(0, 31.2, 0.2))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", function(d) {
    return colorScale(scale(d))
  });
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to use two scales, just use math before passing the number to the color scale for creating 9 bins.